# Google Cloud Platform swagger openapi config yaml file isn't properly rejecting requests that don't contain my api key in the header

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-platform, postman, api-key, api-gateway

I have this config file for my Google Cloud Platform API Gateway endpoint:

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  title: api-1
  description: API Gateway First for Testing
  version: 1.0.0
securityDefinitions:
  api_key_header:
    type: apiKey
    name: key
    in: header
schemes:
  - https
produces:
  - application/json
paths:
  /endpoint1:
    post:
      summary: Simple echo service
      operationId: echo-1
      x-google-backend:
        address: https://<CLOUD FUNCTION GEN 2 NAME>-<MORE IDENTIFYING INFO>-uc.a.run.app
      security:
        - api_key_header: []
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
```

As you can see, I'm trying to require an API key in order for my server to call the API safely. In my opinion, an API key is necessary for security to prevent someone from figuring out my endpoint and spaming the GCP function.

I created an API key to use for this API endpoint (I censored a lot of data for privacy reasons):
[image]

I tried to call the endpoint in Postman like this:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://<API CALLABLE ENDPOINT>.uc.gateway.dev/endpoint1' \
--header 'X-goog-api-key: <MY API KEY HERE>' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8' \
--data-raw '{
    "name": "Test1"
}'
```

The problem is that the Postman request works... always lol. No matter what incorrect API key I use for the header...

I noticed that there is no place where I'm directly referencing my API key name. I'm not sure where I'd put this. How do I alter this API Gateway to properly reject requests that do not contain the correct API key?

Answer (score 0):

All available formats are specified on this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/openapi-limitations#api_key_definition_limitations).

When requesting Api Key through the header, you have to match a specific name which is "x-api-key".
So for your openapi file, it gives the following securityDefinitions:

```
securityDefinitions:
  api_key_header:
    type: "apiKey"
    name: "x-api-key"
    in: "header"
```

And the curl request should have this header then:

```
--header 'x-api-key: <MY API KEY HERE>'
```